# Is this function continuous on the plane

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers, harmonic-functions

Let $1<p<2$ and let $\mathrm{Arg}:\mathbb R^2\backslash\{(0,0)\}\to \mathbb R^2$ be the argument function defined as (see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Argument_(complex_analysis))
$$
\mathrm{Arg}(x,y)=
\begin{cases}
\arctan \left({\frac {y}{x}}\right),&\text{ if }x>0\\
\arctan \left({\frac {y}{x}}\right)+\pi, &\text{ if $x<0$ and $y\geq 0$} \\
\arctan \left({\frac {y}{x}}\right)-\pi, &\text{ if $x<0$ and $y< 0$} \\
\frac {\pi }{2},&\text{ if $x=0$ and $y> 0$} \\
-\frac {\pi }{2},&\text{ if $x=0$ and $y< 0$} \\
\text{undefined},&\text{ if $x=0$ and $y= 0$} \\
\end{cases}
$$
Let $f(x,y)$ be defined by
$$
f(x,y)=\begin{cases}
(x^2+y^2)^{\frac p 2}\cos (p \mathrm{Arg(x,y)}), &\text{ if }(x,y)\neq (0,0)\\
 0, &\text{ if }(x,y)=(0,0)
\end{cases}.
$$
In another notation,
$$
f(x,y)=\begin{cases}
(x^2+y^2)^{\frac p 2}\cos (p \arctan \frac y x), &\text{ if }x>0\\
(x^2+y^2)^{\frac p 2}\cos (\frac {p \pi}2), &\text{ if }x=0\\
(x^2+y^2)^{\frac p 2}\cos (p\pi-p \arctan \frac {|y|} {|x|}), &\text{ if }x<0\\
\end{cases}.
$$
My question is: is $f$ continuous and (further, harmonic) on $\mathbb R^2$?

Comment: As a complex valued function $$f(x,y) = \operatorname{Re}(z^p)$$ which has a branch cut for all noninteger values of $p$ (i.e. check what happens on the negative real ($x$) axis)

Comment: @NinadMunshi but there is a $\cos$ in $f$ and $\cos(p\pi)=\cos(-p\pi)$.

Comment: But what about the second derivative?

Comment: @NinadMunshi That requires further computation and I also doubt if this is harmonic. But it seems that $f$ is at least continuous, right?